# Export gpg secret key without passphrase

Tags: gnupg

In gpg 1.4.16 I can `gpg --export-secret-keys <key>` without a passphrase, and it isn't a problem. However, I cannot find anyway to do this in v2.1.9. It asks if I am okay with no passphase, I confirm, and it skips the key. There must be some configuration option to have it do as I please. What is it?

Comment: Same here on Arch Linux, I'm having this issue with our test key.

Comment: For what it is worth, I am using Arch, as well. So maybe this problem is limited to us.

Comment: I already had gpg1 installed from AUR for some reason, it works.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone still being hit by this problem (like me):
It was a regression in gpg versions beginning at 2.1.0 which was fixed 
in 2.1.13.

See [discussion](https://dev.gnupg.org/T2324) and [fix](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/commit/c41c46fa84cabbed74a13ded51fc3a817a919367).